# Need to set path to the newly created net user

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, ftp, server

I am creating a net user with c# code. I need to set a proper folder path for the user every time so  is this possible  or not .if this is possible then please help me to do it this task take my three days .my code is below :

```
 ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
 procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 procStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
 procStartInfo.Arguments = "/env /user:" + "192.168.0.64/Administrator" + "cmd /K \"NET USER pky112 Admin123# /ADD    \"";

 procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

 ///command contains the command to be executed in cmd
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

 proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

 var sas=    proc.Start();
```

Comment: what error / problem do you face ?

Comment: i have created  a  ftp site. now when i create a net user with this code  and i access with filezila then the ftp website full path open .but i need to share only one folder with user .so i need to set path for the newly created user

Comment: You want to assing user to a folder by executing command in c# application right? When you lunch this command by yourself it works ok? Problem is only with executing it in c# or there is problem with command when you lunch it?

Comment: can you please explain it @cezary

Comment: The above code creates a separate process.  What type of ASP.NET site is this?  Web Forms, MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating another process, consider using the built-in impersonation feature of ASP.NET.  In the web.config file, configure the following:

```
<identity impersonate="true"
      userName="domain\user" 
      password="password" />
```

Of course you would need to replace the information for `username` and `password` according to your environment.  For more security, you could even retrieve as follows:

```
userName="registry:HKLM\Software\AspNetIdentity,Name"
password="registry:HKLM\Software\AspNetIdentity,Password"
```

Hope this helps!